# vpc subnet change wont let me start emr cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to move our emr clusters to a new VPC (new subnets).
When the cluster is started, it fails on:

TerminatingService role EMR_DefaultRole has insufficient ec2 permissions. Refer to policy arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonElasticMapReduceRole for more information

and thats about it. The role nor its connected roles do not have any subnet specific or vpc specific definitions. Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this delete the current roles and create new default roles.

This AWS knowledge article might help you solve this problem.

[EMR_DefaultRole is invalid](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-default-role-invalid/)

Summary:

> The creation and deletion of instance profiles associated with the
>   default roles are automatically handled by the console. This error can
>   occur if the instance profile associated with the EMR_DefaultRole or
>   EMR_EC2_DefaultRole is not configured correctly, or if the current
>   configuration for the instance profile is no longer sufficient to
>   launch an EMR cluster.
>
> As a workaround, you can delete both EMR_DefaultRole and
>   EMR_EC2_DefaultRole and the instance profile associated with them.
>   Deleting a role does not automatically delete the instance profile, so
>   you need to delete it manually.