# EMR Cluster Bootstrap fails on s3 retrieval, though it has access

Tags: amazon-web-services

We moved EMR cluster creation between vpc's based on the question and solution here:

[vpc subnet change wont let me start emr cluster](https://serverfault.com/questions/888178/vpc-subnet-change-wont-let-me-start-emr-cluster)

But now when the clusters start they fail on s3 retrieval, though it should have access since the policy is allow on s3:*